# binary file not writing data in "ab" mode in python

Tags: python, function, binaryfiles

I have user.dat binary file in ./data folder(in my project directory) I am trying to append data in this file in "ab" mode but nothing is happening but when I use "wb" mode data writes to it without any problem

```
import os,pickle
absolutePath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
def ap():
    data = ["B","2"]
    with open(absolutePath+"\\data\\user.dat","ab") as f:
        pickle.dump([data],f)
```

**Note**: In appending mode dump function returns `None` on execution

Comment: unable to reproduce https://replit.com/@JoranBeasley/CompatibleNotedDecompilers

Comment: Have you actually called `ap()` after defining it?

Comment: @Timus obviously yes

Comment: Then I agree with @JoranBeasley: Can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: @MrCoder, don't assume _anything_ is obvious. It is your job to ask your question as clearly as possible. Providing a [mre] is a good way to do that. See [ask].

Comment: This may be a Windows issue

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the mode but with your file path. In "ab" mode, program tries to find the file and add contents to it whereas in "wb" mode, it creates the file and writes contents to it. That's why your code works fine for "wb" mode but not "ab" mode. Please check whether the file that you are trying to append to and the path that you are giving in the program are the same.
I ran the following program and it runs fine.

```
import os,pickle
def ap():
    data = ["B","2"]
    with open("/home/ubuntu/data/user.dat","ab") as f:
        pickle.dump([data],f)
ap()
```

~

Comment: appending mode does also creates a file if doesn't exist [here is geeksforgeeks article about 'ab'](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-append-to-a-file/), :=-( I think I must dump the idea of binary file instead of this I should use SQl

Comment: or use a delimiter of some sort or write separate files for each pickle ... or as mentioned put the pickles as rows in a db ... or evaluate if pickle is the appropriate mechanism

Comment: @JoranBeasley I have just made a solution for my problem since the data isn't that large to eat up RAM space if loaded in an array, so the solution for this is I must load the data in an array and then append the data that I want to append and open the file in `wb` mode and then write it in the file :-)